# Как сделать так что бы программа после того как словить ошибку возвращалась к началу?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    print('Калькулятор activated')
    try:
        x=float(input('Введите первое число: '))#берем 1 число
        y=float(input('Введите второе число: '))#берём 2 число
    except: ValueError, print('Неверное значение цифр')

    print('Помните, на ноль делить НЕЛЬЗЯ!')
    symbol=input('Введите знак +, -, /, * ') 
    if symbol=='+': 
        print('Ответ', x+y)
    elif symbol=='-':
        print('Ответ', x-y)
    elif symbol=='*':
        print('Ответ', x*y)
    elif symbol=='/':
        print('Ответ', x/y)
    else: print('Неверный знак')
```

Answer (score 3):

Обратите внимание на две строчки с комментариями

```
while True:
    print('Калькулятор activated')
    try:
        x = float(input('Введите первое число: '))
        y = float(input('Введите второе число: '))
    except ValueError:  # Вот тут у вас вообще был неправильный синтаксис
        print('Неверное значение цифр')
        continue  # А вот это надо добавить, чтобы возвращалось к началу

    print('Помните, на ноль делить НЕЛЬЗЯ!')
    symbol = input('Введите знак +, -, /, * ') 
    if symbol == '+': 
        print('Ответ', x+y)
    elif symbol == '-':
        print('Ответ', x-y)
    elif symbol == '*':
        print('Ответ', x*y)
    elif symbol == '/':
        print('Ответ', x/y)
    else: print('Неверный знак')
```